# October CMS.. create user with different database

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

I am trying to build a multi user system and each user has different database.. is it possible in october cms.. 
So all the user access one login url.. 
So i don't need to install another fresh octobercms in the server..

Comment: i guess just for login you need one database for use credential comparison , right

Comment: another question how do you check for authenticated user in different database ?

Comment: Oo.. so if all login data in one database and each user data in different database.. so when user login and authenticated the system redirect user to each database.. how about that is that possible..? Or i still have to install fresh octobercms for each user..

Comment: @IsralBustami No you don't, you can set the Database connection during runtime - What are you building so we can help you better ?

Comment: i can suggest that  may be you use , multi domain means sub domain for each new use and based on domain in configuration you can select database , it will work on same code base with different database (if you can make run-time sub-domains by api or you own vps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're referring to a [Multitenancy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/saas-tenancy-app-design-patterns).

You basically have two options :

a) Shared Database

b) Multi tenant Databases ( What you are asking )

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/hyn/multi-tenant) laravel package to get an idea how to implement it but Keep in mind that building model relations across databases can be a pain and don't forget about future migrations ect..

The general idea here is (b) ;

- Create a Tenant / Users Table on your Main Database
- Store in this table each user's access info ( Host, DB Access .. )
- Create Middlewares to handle logins, database connections, redirects, security for each requests..

If you're just playing around there's nothing wrong with it but I wouldn't recommend it for a commercial project unless you're experienced enough.

Having said that, If you want to proceed with option (a) all you need to do is add a `tenant_id` field to all tables / relations and to all queries as a security precaution.

Comment: I am building a system where the users is community in my case is churches.. front end is providing each users event and activity in a week.. i want to build a single door for users to access backend(cms).. so i believe if users use one database will be very large and complicated database.. so i wonder if i can redirect each users with different database..

Comment: I think multitenancy is what isn't it?

Comment: Do you mean your tenants are the Churches ? Where each church has its own backend access ( multiple users per church ) and each church will have its own front-end ( custom domain church1.com , church2.com ect.. ) or will all churches share a front-end ( kind of directory ) ?

Comment: Yes.. so all churches will use the same front end  template and layout but its own data(either custom sub-domain or directory).. more like social media but it only and only display churches data(event n activity).. where all churches data enter by operator from single login url.. so it is easy for me as superadmin to monitor the system..

Comment: You think multitenancy will be fit for me.

Comment: Yes but the question is why you want to have separate databases, you can do it with a shared one, will make ur life easier.  One solution would be create a tenant (church ) table and store that info there like domain, your clients would have to point that domain to your server and you also have to add it to route traffic to your app. In octobercms there's a new config environment, where you can add these domains,  and you can easily write a middleware to load chuch specific data based on the host.  When it comes to users logins a shared table with a church_id is ok, a User belongs to a Church

Comment: and a Church hasMany or hasOne Users/admin. You can create the church admin section as a front-end ( not Octobers) and as regards loading church specific data such as events, activity shouldn't be hard , MyApp::getTenant()->events ... Where getTenant gets the active church based on the host, logged in user ect..

Comment: Ok.. the reason i want to have separate database is each tenant has many tables  at least 12 tables so  imagine if we have more than 10 tenant.. hundreds of tables need to be build for this system not the october tables.. so actually its just a thought.. and i have check on laravel tenancy.. it seems that its not an easy thing to integrate with october..

Comment: So you think october its not the best tools to build this system.. i am an still.an amateur on developing application.. so when i found out october was glad.

Comment: So i need to build this from.scratch

Comment: I will use fresh install october for each user..  while i am.figuring out to build with tenancy..

Comment: October is just a cms like any other it really depends on your design. I gave you my opinion that it's doable with October, I did a similar project, and I recommended you work on a shared database. Now it's up to you to choose what makes you comfortable. You will not know unless you try something.

Comment: I really appreciate your opinion

Comment: i find that october can do multiple database connection.. can i implement this? 
`Db::connection('connection_name')`

Comment: I want to implement that for each user  to have different db connection